# Getting client IP address in nginx/flask application

Tags: python, nginx, flask, uwsgi

This question seems to be asked often, but I have not found a good resolution to the problem I am having.

I have a flask application that is behind nginx. The app and nginx communicate via uwsgi unix socket.  The application has a publicly exposed endpoint that is exposed via Route53.  It is also exposed via AWS API Gateway.  The reason for this dual exposure is that the application is replacing an existing Lambda solution.  With the API Gateway, I can support legacy requests until they can transition to the new publicly exposed endpoint.  An additional fact about my application, it is running in a Kubernetes pod, behind a load balancer.

I need to get access to the IP address of the client that made the request so I can use geoIP lookups and exclude collection of data for users outside of US (GDPR) among other things.  With two paths into the application, I have two different ways to get to the IP address.

**Hitting the endpoint from API Gateway**

When I come in through the legacy path, I get an X-Forwarded-For, but I am only seeing IP addresses that are registered to Amazon.  I was using the first one in the list, but I only see one or two different IP address.  This is a test environment, and that may be correct, but I don't think so because when I hit it from my local browser, I do not find my IP.

**Directly hitting the endpoint:**

In this case, there is no data in the X-Forwarded-For list, and the only ip address I can find is request.remote_addr.  This, unfortunately only has the IP address of either the pod, or maybe the load balancer.  I'm not sure which as it is in the same class, but matches neither.  Regardless, it is definitely not the client IP address.  I found documentation in nginx that describes available variables including $realip_remote_addr.  However, when I logged that value, it was the same as remote_addr.

The following is the code that I am using to get the remote_addr:

```
def remote_addr(self, request):
    x_forwarded_for = request.headers.get("X-Forwarded-For")
    if x_forwarded_for:
        ip_list = x_forwarded_for.split(",")
        return ip_list[0]
    else:
        return request.remote_addr
```

If it is helpful, this is my nginx server config:

```
server {
  listen 8443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/certs/cert;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/certs/key;
  ssl_dhparam /etc/certs/dhparam.pem;
  ssl_protocols       TLSv1.2;
  ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;
  ssl_ciphers "EECDH+ECDSA+AESGCM EECDH+aRSA+AESGCM EECDH+ECDSA+SHA384 EECDH+ECDSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+SHA384 EECDH+aRSA+SHA256 EECDH+aRSA+RC4 EECDH EDH+aRSA HIGH !RC4 !aNULL !eNULL !LOW !3DES !MD5 !EXP !PSK !SRP !DSS";
  server_tokens off;


  location = /log {
    limit_except POST {
      deny all;
    }
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
  }

  location = /ping {
    limit_except GET {
      deny all;
    }
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock;
  }

  location = /health-check {
    return 200 '{"response": "Healthy"}';
  }

  location /nginx_status {
    stub_status;
  }
}
```

I have spent over a day trying to sort this out.  I am sure that the solution is trivial and is likely caused by lack of knowledge/experience using nginx.

Comment: I've determined that if I go through the API Gateway, the correct IP address is being returned as the first element of the X-Forwarded-For.  The reason it looked suspicious is that my service is running in our Non Prod environment and all the traffic comes from the same IP address block.  However, I still have no way of getting to the client IP address if I hit the endpoint directly, i.e. no proxies.

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes, by default do not preserve the client address in the target container (https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/create-external-load-balancer/).

Therefore, I solved that by editing my Nginx ingress configuration, where I changed the `externalTrafficPolicy` property to `local`.

```yaml
...
  ports:
    - port: 8765
      targetPort: 9376
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  type: LoadBalancer
...
```

However, be aware that if you change that you may have a risk of unbalanced traffic among the pods:

> Cluster obscures the client source IP and may cause a second hop to another node, but should have good overall load-spreading. Local preserves the client source IP and avoids a second hop for LoadBalancer and NodePort type Services, but risks potentially imbalanced traffic spreading.